# How can I obtain the CRC from a CAN(Controller Area Network) message frame?

Tags: c#, perl, crc, can-bus

I have a project in which I need to create a perl script to parse a .hex file into a .can file full of CAN frames for to be sent. Once the file has been parsed it is going to be read by a C# based GUI that will translate those lines into proper CAN messages to be sent.

The list of aspects that I need to include for the .can is the following:

1. Add delays to TX commands
2. Add comments that the parser will ignore
3. Add a file header comment that the parser will ignore
   When file was create, which file, parser version… etc.
4. Add a CRC (on the file itself)
5. Add an Application CRC (written to certain Flash memory location)

This is an example of the .hex file that I am parsing:

```
:020000040000FA
:10000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00
:10001000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0
:10002000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
:10003000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD0
:10004000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC0
:10005000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB0
:10006000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA0
:10007000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF90
:10008000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80
:10009000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF70
```

Out of this list I am only missing number 4 and 5. I've been reading about what is CRC and how to make use of it, so I have some knowledge on the topic, but I do not know to implement points 4 and 5. I would appreciate some guidance on how to approach this issue. Below a sample of the .can file that I cam using:

```
//File used: app1FULL.hex
//Parser version: 0.2 alpha
//Date: Thu Oct 13 16:47:55 2016
TX:10:1537:8:45:EF:0B:F0:FF:FF:FF:FF //load flash
TX:10:1538:8:FA:CF:11:F0:FB:CF:12:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1539:8:E9:CF:13:F0:EA:CF:14:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1540:8:E1:CF:15:F0:E2:CF:16:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1541:8:D9:CF:17:F0:DA:CF:18:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1542:8:F3:CF:19:F0:F4:CF:1A:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1543:8:F6:CF:1B:F0:F7:CF:1C:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1544:8:F8:CF:1D:F0:F5:CF:1E:F0 //load flash
TX:10:1536:5:B:0:16:0:40:00:00:00:00:64 //flash write
RX:1000:1535:3:B:0:16:64 //expect response
PRINT:Boot has failed:Boot received all messages successfully
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I just edited the question to make it clearer. I need to  add a CRC for every can frame in the .can file. The .can file is generated by a perl script parsing a .hex file. The main question is, what do I need to implement on the perl script to add the CRC into the generated .can file.

Comment: you have an example of the final format that your GUI is going to read? It could be an older file that's not related to the current one, but it might give hints about what you need to do.

Comment: Yes that's an example of the final format @simbabque. But I'm afraid I'm no quite getting your advice on the second part of the question. Could you clarify or expand on that?

Comment: So the file you posted is the expected output? In that case, add what you have right now. If you need to modify the data and you don't know _how_ to modify it, comparing before and after would help.

Comment: Got it! Going to make those changes now...